# How to make a button appear at the right top of the canvas

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I am using `C#` with `XAML`. I want my button to be always at the top right corner
regardless of screen size.

I tried to do it like this:

```
<Button x:Name="SubmitExperimentBtn" Content="Submit" FontWeight="Bold" 
    FontSize="18.667" Foreground="#FF0D0D0E" BorderBrush="#FF091F4B" 
    BorderThickness="1" Width="115" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
    Background="Black" Opacity="10"
    Click="SubmitExperimentBtn_Click" Margin="522,8,0,2">
</Button>
```

It looks like it's on the right top but when I am Debugging it open the explorer
and put it in the middle (depending on screen size)

How to make it appear on the right top convert of the canvas?

Comment: i only have "Canvas.Top" && "Canvas.Left"

Comment: `Canvas.Right` and `Canvas.Bottom` exists in WPF, not in Silverlight. Do you really need `Canvas` as a container? You can use `Grid`, for example.

Comment: i have to use Canvas it's not my system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to make it work.
because i'm using Silverlight i don't have Canvas.Right just Top and Left
i took the screen resolution in runtime and then
change the button position to the Top Right corner.
here is the code:

```
    //for the screen resolution
    double screen_resolution_x = double.Parse(HtmlPage.Document.Body.GetProperty
("clientWidth").ToString());
    double screen_resolution_y= double.Parse(HtmlPage.Document.Body.GetProperty
("clientHeight").ToString());

    //to move the botton on the Canvas
     ((Button)canvas1.FindName("SubmitExperimentBtn")).SetValue
(Canvas.LeftProperty, screen_reolution_x);
                ((Button)canvas1.FindName("SubmitExperimentBtn")).SetValue
(Canvas.TopProperty, screen_reolution_y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Canvas is almost always the wrong thing to use. Grid and StackPanel is what you should be using for these auto  flow scenarios. Canvas is for absolute layout and not for auto flow so you're really going against what it is meant for.
If you insist though, use the SizeChanged event of the parent element to detect when the canvas changes it's visible area (has to be the parent because canvas is always infinitely large) then set the Left value based on it. Ie

Canvas.SetLeft(myButton,e.NewSize.Width-myButton.ActualWidth)

Answer (score 0):

If your button is in a Canvas, you should use the attached properties for positioning:

```
<Canvas>
  <Button x:Name="SubmitExperimentBtn" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Right="10"></Button>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: i tried to do Canvas.Right but i just have Canvas.left (and i don't know how "much" left i have to go)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Margin and VerticalAlignment as below with HorizontalAlignment to Right.

```
<Button x:Name="SubmitExperimentBtn" Content="Submit" FontWeight="Bold" 
        FontSize="18.667" Foreground="#FF0D0D0E" BorderBrush="#FF091F4B" 
        BorderThickness="1" Width="115" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Background="Black" Opacity="10"
        Click="SubmitExperimentBtn_Click" Margin="0,8,20,2"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right">
</Button>
```